# Two readers have different response to GET DATA command

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I have two smart card readers connected to my computer :

1. [ACS ACR122U](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader) contactless reader
2. [CRT-603-CZ1](http://www.china-creator.com/products_detail/&productId=31.html) contactless reader

I read the manual of both readers. As mentioned in the manuals, both use the following APDU commands for *GET DATA* APDU commands :

```java
CLA  | INS  |     P1    |  P2  |  Le
0xFF | 0xCA | 0x00/0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00

P1 = 0x00 --> UID will return.
P1 = 0x01 --> ATS or Historical Byte of ATS will return.
```

Well, I put an ISO14443 (Maybe Mifare) card in the field of *ACR122U* reader first and then in the field of *CRT-603-CZ1* and I tried above commands:

```java
OSC:> OSC.exe -r "ACS ACR122 0" -s FFCA000000
Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "ACS ACR122 0" -s FFCA010000
Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0" -s FFCA000000
Sending: FF CA 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x00):
FF 16 7F 29 ...)

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0" -s FFCA010000
Sending: FF CA 01 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
```

As you see above, the results are different. Actually *ACR122U* can't return the ATS and UID of this card.

Well, I repeat the above step with a *JCOPv2.4.2r3* card:

```java
OSC:> OSC.exe -r "ACS ACR122 0" -s FFCA000000
Sending: FF CA 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
EF B6 09 2E ....

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "ACS ACR122 0" -s FFCA010000
Sending: FF CA 01 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
0E 78 F7 B1 02 4A 43 4F 50 32 34 32 52 33 .x...JCOP242R3

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0" -s FFCA000000
Sending: FF CA 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x00):
EF B6 09 2E ....

OSC:> OSC.exe -r "CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0" -s FFCA010000
Sending: FF CA 01 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
4A 43 4F 50 32 34 32 52 33 00 JCOP242R3.
```

And as you see, both returns almost the same result.

**Can anybody help me to understand why I receive different results for the first card?**

*Note that OCS.exe is execution file of [OpenSC-Tool](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/QuickStart)*

Answer (score 0):

You are addressing the respective **reader**, not the card, so differences are likely.

My assumption is, that your first card, while supporting ISO 14443 is not a type A card and therefore has no ATS. It might worth to check, whether the reader supports type B at all and how the ATQB would be retrieved for a type B card.

Comment: Thank you.For the first card, ACR122 doen't return UID, but the CRT-603 return it. why? For the second card, both works equal.

Comment: _You are addressing the respective reader, not the card_ I can't address the card in OpenSC-Tool. moreover, there is only one card in that interface and I don't think it can make any change.